# Is it bad to use window property to create variables?

Tags: javascript

(Sorry for my poor English)

I finally realized why it's better to use `let` or `const` instead of `var` because `var` can't work with `window` properties!

However, is it a good idea still to use `window` properties as variable names just because you can bypass the problem by using other two keywords of creating variables?

For example:

```
var name  = 'James';
console.log(name);
```

The above won't work because I'm using `var` keyword however if I used `let` or `const`, this wouldn't cause any error!

So once again, just because I can should I ?

Comment: why wouldn't it work? `var name = 'James'; console.log(name);` should work ... `var` and `let` simply work in given context, `window.var` is global, as `window` is global variable itself

Comment: How would you avoid using `window` properties? Let's say you decide to use `fnord` as a variable name and it doesn't exist on `window` *yet*. What happens if it's added to the standard tomorrow? Do you change all your code? What happens if you add a library that adds `window.fnord`?

Comment: @VLAZ well... and what happens if someone adds $ as a standard and it won't be jQuery? This is kinda too way ahead thinking

Comment: @FlashThunder there is `window.name` and it's infamous for causing issues when it clashes with variable names. `var name` in the global context will *not* create a separate variable but would still re-use the `window.name` property. Depending on the mode the browser window is in, you might not be able to overwrite it, so `var name = "James"; console.log(name);` might result in something unexpected. [Try it in a stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here) to see that problem in action

Comment: @FlashThunder the answer to the `$` is in the question. You use `const` and avoid clashes.

Comment: @VLAZ yes, `name` literally is not a good idea

Answer (score 7):

Using variable names that exist as properties on the `window` object was never the real problem. Using them for *global variables* was (and still is). But if you are in a local scope, e.g. inside a `function`, you can name your local variables however you like.

If you cannot avoid global variables, you should strife to use as few as possible, and yes you should try to avoid collisions with other globals, be they properties of `window` or not. Using `let` or `const` just ensures that *if* they are `window` properties, your custom variable will shadow them, but you will still break other code that relies on these to be accessible as global variables with the builtin value. However, most of the time you cannot avoid global variables you also cannot avoid `var`, as `let` and `const` cannot be redeclared.

Answer (score 1):

## var

Function-scoped variable. It is visible in the current function. If it's outside all functions, then it's visible globally, assuming it's not in module scope.

## let

Block-scoped variable. It's visible in the `{}` block where it was defined.

## const

Block-scoped constant. Like `let`, it's block-scoped, but this one is constant.

## object property

`window` is an object, so let's think about objects in general.

```
window.foo = "bar"; console.log(window.foo);
```

## "Better"

One is not "better" than the other by definition. You will need to think about your needs and the conventions your team has agreed upon and apply them. Setting window attributes should not be a custom in general, because you are making it global, but sometimes you need to set `window` properties. Again: always think about what you need to achieve.

Comment: "*If it's outside all functions, then it's visible globally.*" unless it's in module scope.